# The type initializer for "Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport" threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am getting below exception when trying to access the azure key vault.

> The type initializer for "Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport" threw an exception.' FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)

Below is my code:
When trying to create the secretclient object, it is throwing that exception:

```
           SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClient(
            new Uri(vaultUrl),
           new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret)
        );

        var value1= secretClient.GetSecret("Key1");
        var value2= secretClient.GetSecret("Key2");
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {value1.Value.Value, value2.Value.Value}
        };
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my side, it works fine. Please check the values of **tenantId**, **clientId** and **clientSecret**. Also, you can check if you are using the correct **dependencies**. Here is my whole code for your reference.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TonyTestGraph
{
    class KeyValutTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClient(
               new Uri("https://tonykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"),
              new ClientSecretCredential("xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "366b3XXX113-4d73-ac2b-cfe920b3a6ae", "HMeQ41RWacxuFgxxx02Ce43qb.1.K-~S")
           );

                var value1 = secretClient.GetSecret("connectionString");
            Console.WriteLine(value1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Package version:**

Azure.Identity 1.2.0-preview.3

Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets 4.0.3